# Loopback and default sorting

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I'm starting to study loopback.
I created my app, and below this model:

```
{
  "name": "movimenti",
  "plural": "movimenti",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "mov_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "mov_tipo": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "mov_valore": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

I connected the model to my MySQL DB:

```
"movimenti": {
    "dataSource": "banca",
    "public": true
}
```

I launched the application, and went to the address indicated.
I questioned the GET method, having this error:

> "stack": "Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'\n

but I do not have an ID field in my table.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loopback will automatically add an `id` column if none of the properties of a model is mentioned as id.

Assuming for your model, property `mov_id` is the id. Define so in the model by adding `id: true` line: [Reference](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#id-properties)

```
{
  ...
  "properties": {
    "mov_id": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "id":true
    },
  ...
}
```